# Twitter4J: Poll / Polls Support

Tags: java, api, twitter, twitter4j

**Hello dear community,**

does anybody have a clue how to deal with [**Twitter-polls**](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/twitter-polls) while using the [**Twitter4J-Library**](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html)?

The [**statuses**](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html) from a user's timeline does only contain the text of a poll. Neither the options nor the result.

Does someone figured it out? Is there any hint in the [**Javadocs of Twitter4J**](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/index.html)?

Kind regards 
*OtenMoten*

Answer (score 0):

There is no Twitter API support for polls, so no API libraries support them, regardless of the programming language.

Comment: This is very sad. What is about https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/creatives/api-reference/poll.html ?

Comment: That's a specific feature for the Ads API which is not part of the standard API features. It will only work with polls created as Ads creatives.

Comment: One more additional thing - the premium search APIs does include an enrichment that shows poll metadata - the options for the poll, not the results - if you are in one of the paid tiers.